# If I delete or close google account, will it also delete or close my adsense account?

Tags: google-adsense, accounts

I have a Google account that I want to delete or close, but it is linked to Google Adsense account also. Plus, I use this account across all my websites and youtube videos for monetizing. So, my question is that if I close or delete this account, will it also affect my adsense account. If so, is there a way to keep adsense account and delete everything else?

Comment: Do you have an alternative Google account which you can link it to?

Comment: Most likely yes, unless other users of AdSense have been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete your Google Account, it will not delete your AdSense account. However, you will be blocked from AdSense as you will not be able to access it using the invalid account. In other words, I do not think it is possible to achieve what you want to do.

However, if you have an alternative Google account, you could look into transferring it. [I recommend this article](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/transfer-google-adsense-account-16722.html).OR view the [Google Support](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1208348?hl=en).

Comment: So, technically I still should be able to use my Adsense account for monetizing, but it is just that I won't be able to access the account to view or make any changes. Is that right? I do have other gmail accounts that I could transfer my Adsense account to.

Comment: Yes technically, but would not recommend that as it would be difficult to make changes or close in the future without access. Would definitely transfer to alternative email.You can at least add the other email as an administrator, even if you don't want to remove the old Google address. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me on my site  but there is a solution. What I did was to change the domain to another thing that is different from the domain I want to use for adsense.

Like what I did in the image below I changed the domain to `bowwwww.com`

[image]

Comment: In other words you are changing the domain name to something fake in the old AdSense application?

Comment: yes dear. if not it will not be closed ooo